# Find xpath of an element from text contained within a div [Robot framework]

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, robotframework

I need to retrieve the xpath of element on a page but all I know about the element is that it will contain a certain string let's say "required text" and that it will sit in a div. I would like to search the page for this string and return the xpath to this div.

I have tried something like:

```
${findXPath} =   Get Element Attribute   //*[contains(text(),'required text')]   xpath
```

but this returns nothing.

Comment: I guess this is your xpath `//*[contains(text(),'required text')]` already where `required text` would be variable value for each different element.

Answer (score 0):

**XPath** isn't an [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139)'s attribute. [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) is a element [Locating Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890).

So [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) won't be able to return the ***xpath***